# DOCTYPE Xml Request in wso2 esb 5.0

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB and my first task is to consume a xml web service which has a validating it's request via .DTD file.

below is the request which i need to pass

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE COMMAND PUBLIC "-//Ocam//DTD XML Command 1.0//EN" "xml/command.dtd">
<COMMAND>
<TYPE>EXUSRBALREQ</TYPE>
<DATE>14-03-17</DATE>
</COMMAND>
```

First i framed the xml request and then via xslt mediator i am adding the `DOCTYPE`.

However wso2 esb is not passing the expected request.
Below is the request which is being passed.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><COMMAND>
   <TYPE>EXUSRBALREQ</TYPE>
   <DATE>01-01-2017</DATE>   
</COMMAND></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Due to this the request is failing.

I have added `"<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>"` in axis2.xml

Can you please help me out.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try to look around for alternate solution however it looks like wso2 esb doesn't support .DTD request.

Hence i have written a RESTful web service so now wso2 esb will frame xml request and pass it to RESTful WS and webservice will add

This approach is working for me

Comment: Add following ling into your ESB /wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/conf/axis2 file (axis2.xml)                                                           <parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter> This is worked for me.

Comment: Yes, i had added the same as mentioned in the question earlier however when checked the TCPDUMP the DOCTYPE declaration was not going through hence i had to write out a RESTful WS.